# TreasuryDirect - workaround for requiring certified forms to change bank account info

Tags: united-states, savings-bonds

TreasuryDirect  makes it a real pain to change bank account information.  They require a signed form, certified at a bank.  This is impossible if you do all your banking online, and it seems ridiculous for the small amounts of money I'm dealing with.

Has anyone figured out a workaround - for example, is there some way to open a new account and then send myself the bonds to the other account?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not, and what's worse is that many bank officials will look at you like you have three heads when you ask them to sign something from treasurydirect.gov.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: it looks like this may no longer be a requirement.  I was able to withdraw from TreasuryDirect into another bank account without issue.